# assertTextPresent equivalent in phpunit

Tags: phpunit, assertions

I'm trying to test for the presence of a string somewhere in a long webpage. Using PHPUnit's assertRegExp if the string is not found it prints out the entire page and then finishes with `matches PCRE pattern "/xxxxxx/".` According to the [documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertRegExp) I should be able to specify a message a third that will be printed out if the test fails. That message is printed, followed by the full page source. What I'd like to do is just print the message. Using Selenium in my previous apps I used `assertTextPresent` and it would just print out confirmation that the text was/was not found, without filling my screen.
I have tried wrapping the `assertRegExp` in a try-catch but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `assertContains()` instead of `assertRegexp()`.

PHPUnit is responsible for printing out the failed text, and this differs from one assert method to another. It just might work.

If it does not, open an issue at [PHPUnit's issue tracker](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues) about PHPUnit printing too much out.

Comment: Looks like the same result. It prints the message I told it to, plus the entire source of the page :/

Answer (score 0):

I am using the getBodyText() method to get all page content and than I use assertTextPresent() to check the presence of pattern.

```
 $this->assertTextPresent($this->getBodyText(), 'text to find');
```

The solution has been positivly tested with latest phpunit 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

I use `assertTrue(stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false, 'Failed assertion message');`